# Adding a string to a panel from a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

I'm working on a program that allows a user to enter a message. When the user presses on the "message" menu item located in my frame, a `JOptionPane` input dialog box pops up prompting them to enter a string. The problem is that I have to now obtain that string and stick it into my panel class. In addition I also allow the user to select a shape and color from a different dialog box when they press on another menu item also located in my frame. The string has to be on top of the shape I've drawn. I've tried 
draw string but it's not functioning properly. Here is my code which is not working.
I just want the string to draw on my panel when I hit OK on the `JOptionPane`. How would I do that?

In my frame

```
private void messageItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your string");

    // my panel
    drawP.setMessage(message);

}
```

in my Panel

```
public void setMessage(String s) {
    message = s;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // the user can select two different shapes this is
    // a boolean
    if (shape == true) {
        g.setColor(shapeColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
        g.drawString(message, x, y);

    } else {
        g.setColor(shapeColor);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        g.drawString(message, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Adding a string to a panel from a JOPTIONPANE"*  No need to SHOUT at us, and please use correct case for class names.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you call [repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) after you set the message? I tried before, repaint JFrame doesn't seems to works, but repaint JPanel works.

Comment: You could also try invalidate(); repaint(); this should cause the container hierarchy to update and repaint.  It's a little heavy handed, but can get you out of sticky places, especially when the repaint manager feels there's nothing to update

Comment: For this simple task at hand, simple call to `repaint()` after setting the message will do, since it will call `paintcomponent(...)` indirectly, though for doing heavy work related to painting, it's wise to look at other related methods inside `Component Class`[repaint(...)]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint(int, int, int, int)) or [repaint(Rectangle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(java.awt.Rectangle)), +1 though for the answer :-)